# Get Request is passed instead of post request from new.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying out for basic login and registration in ruby on rails, 
**ISSUE: When I click register button from new.html I am getting GET request but I can see method="post" in page source of that html** 
I have posted my code below
new.html.erb

```
    <form>
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :user_name %>
<%= f.text_field :user_name %></br>
<%= f.label :email_id %>
<%= f.text_field :email_id %></br>
<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password %></br>
<%= f.label :college %>
<%= f.text_field :college %></br>
<%= f.label :major %>
<%= f.text_field :major %></br>
<%= f.label :current_job %>
<%= f.text_field :current_job %></br>
<%= f.submit("Create Account",class: "btn btn-primary") %>
<% end %>
</form>
```

My index.html.erb code which is loaded while application starts

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="login">

<%= form_tag("/user/login",:method => :post) do %>
<%= label_tag(:EmailId) %>
<%= text_field_tag(:email, params[:email]) %></br>
<%= label_tag(:password) %>
<%= password_field_tag(:password, params[:password]) %></br>
<%= submit_tag("Log In",class: "btn btn-primary") %>
<%= submit_tag("Register",class: "btn btn-primary") %>

<% end %>
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

My controller code

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.all
  end



  def login
    print "In Sign in controller"
    @user = User.new
    if params[:commit] == 'Register'
      print "inside Register class"
      redirect_to '/users/new'
    else
    @user = User.find(params[:email_id])
    if @user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
        sessions[:userId] = @user.user_id
    end
    end
    end


    def new
    puts "****Inside New Method******"
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
   puts "****Inside create Method******"
  end
 private 
 def user_params
 end

end
```

My Route code

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'users#index'
   resources :users
   post '/users/login' => 'users#login'
```

As per my understanding post request should hit create method, but get /users method is hitting. Please help me out regarding this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a form tag inside another form tag. Remove the  tag at the top of your form. `<%= form_for(@user) %>` takes care everything that's needed to build the correct form.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have nested forms in `new.html.erb`? Remove the first `form` tag

```
<form>
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```